# How to instantiate CameraControl on Android CameraX (1.0.0-alpha07)

Tags: android, android-camerax

When using camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha06" I could instantiale the camera controller using :

```
CameraControl cameraControl = CameraX.getCameraControl(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK);
```

But with camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha07", the function `CameraX.getCameraControl` is not any more recognized.

How can I instantiate CameraControl ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version `1.0.0-alpha07` changed the way CameraX is initialized quite a lot. In order to obtain a `CameraControl` object, you have to get a `Camera` object first. A `Camera` is returned from a `ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle()` method. Basically what you need to do is:

**(If you have already configured your project with the new API, just skip to the last point)**

1. Implement `CameraXConfig.Provider` in your `Application` class and provide the default `Camera2Config` value:

```
class MyApp : Application(), CameraXConfig.Provider {
    override fun getCameraXConfig(): CameraXConfig = Camera2Config.defaultConfig(this)
}
```

2. Obtain an instance of `ProcessCameraProvider`:

```
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
    cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
    ...
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
```

**3. Bind CameraX `UseCase`s and `CameraSelector` to a lifecycle using the `ProcessCameraProvider` instance and get `Camera` and `CameraControl` objects:**

```
// CameraSelector is also a new thing
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().apply {
    requireLensFacing(lensFacing)
}.build()

val preview = ...
val imageCapture = ...
val imageAnalysis = ...

val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalysis)
val cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
```

Check [Camera-Core Version 1.0.0-alpha07 API changes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-core-1.0.0-alpha07) for any additional references.